# How to get call logs for last 10 days using Twilio API?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am working on a Twilio project in which I need to fetch call logs for last 10 days in a single call, but I see no favourable parameters in twilio api docs (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/call#list-get) that can help me. I tried *DateCreated*,*StartTime* parameters but they work differently. Could anyone help me out here please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the code you used and what didn't work about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in the wrong area of the api, i think the area you are looking at is for calls currently in progress.

Try [usage-records](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records)

Sometimes when I'm stuck, I run a curl example in [Twilio's API explorer](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/api-explorer/usage/usage-records); This shows me 2 things:

1. Options used in call
2. What to expect as results

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try the `startTimeAfter` and `startTimeBefore` parameters.

---

```
// Download the Node helper library from twilio.com/docs/node/install
// These identifiers are your accountSid and authToken from
// https://www.twilio.com/console
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

const filterOpts = {
  status: 'completed',
  startTimeAfter: '2016-07-04',
  startTimeBefore: '2016-07-06',
};

client.calls.each(filterOpts, call => console.log(call.direction));
```

***Twilio Docs:***
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/call?code-sample=code-retrieve-completed-calls-from-a-period-of-time&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x

Answer (score 0):

```
curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[ACCOUNT SID]/Calls.json?StartTime%3E=2020-06-01T0&EndTime%3C=2020-07-01' -u [ACCOUT SID]:[AuthToken]
```

This curl script will give you a list of calls from 2020-06-01 to 2020-07-01. Don't forget to substitute your ACCOUNT_SID and AuthToken (without the brackets)